# Disable SSLV3 on lighttpd 1.4.28

Tags: lighttpd

I just installed SSL certificate on my lighttpd server. When running some 3d-party tests they said that `SSLV3` should be disabled for security reasons.

However, as my version don't support `ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"` in configurations file I'm unsure of how to make the changes. It seams like `1.4.29` support it but not `1.4.28`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the tester that only TLS should be enabled.

Consider upgrading lighttpd and libssl. This may require a newer operating system. Given the age of lighttpd 1.4.28 this is a requirement for modern https security.

You can control the cipher list. See this article [Stong SSL Security on lighttpd](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_lighttpd.html) for an example of importing [Mozilla OpSec's list](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS). Beware that you are limited by OpenSSL version.

https://cipherli.st/ is the quick reference version for modern clients.